# insert and update with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Have a problem with my stored procedure (on MySQL). I need the data update process of the table if the record exists, else insert the record. I have:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE saveorUpdate(in product varchar(30), price int, stock int, active varchar(5))

BEGIN

DECLARE id int;

SELECT id_pro FROM products WHERE product=product into id;

IF(id_pro=id)THEN

UPDATE products SET product=product, price=price, stock=stock, active=active 
WHERE id_pro=id;

ELSE

INSERT INTO products (product, price, stock, active) VALUES 
(product, price, stock, active);

END IF;
END
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you are using stored procedure for this? You can use REPLACE... INTO ... statement to perform this operation with single SQL. You need to have replace based on primary key column in this case.

Comment: will look at that as a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your database is MySQL you could just use the **INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY** syntax and scrap the stored procedure stuff.

```
INSERT INTO products (
  product, price, stock, active
) VALUES (
  $product, $price, $stock, $active
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  product=VALUES(product)
 , price=VALUES(price)
 , stock=VALUES(stock)
 , active=VALUES(active)
```

Just an idea. Could be a cleaner and faster to write alternative.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Using the syntax **INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY** can solve this problem, but sometimes we want to know how to do something like this in a procedure. For example, to simplify queries to the database, or then modify the entire procedure by adding more dependencies.
Column parameters should have a different name than column names:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE saveorUpdate (IN inProduct varchar(30), inPrice int, inStock int, inActive varchar(5))
BEGIN
  DECLARE id int;
  SELECT id_pro INTO id FROM products WHERE product=inProduct;
  IF(id IS NULL)THEN
    INSERT INTO products (product, price, stock, active) VALUES (inProduct, inPrice, inStock, inActive);
  ELSE
    UPDATE products SET product=inProduct, price=inPrice, stock=inStock, active=inActive WHERE id_pro=id;
  END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And if they must be the same, table names should be added to column names to distinguish them:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE saveorUpdate (IN product varchar(30), price int, stock int, active varchar(5))
BEGIN
  DECLARE id int;
  SELECT id_pro INTO id FROM products WHERE product=products.product;
  IF(id IS NULL)THEN
    INSERT INTO products (product, price, stock, active) VALUES (products.product, products.price, products.stock, products.active);
  ELSE
    UPDATE products SET product=products.product, price=products.price, stock=products.stock, active=products.active WHERE id_pro=id;
  END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The second problem is the **IF(id_pro=id)THEN** condition. It seems pointless. If the record is not in the database, SELECT will return NULL. So you need to check if id is NULL. If true, call INSERT, if not, call UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the question - stored procedure with INSERT, UPDATE on DUPLICATE.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `manage-business`
(IN `bname` VARCHAR(200)) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
INSERT INTO tbl_company (co_name) VALUES (bname) ON DUPLICATE key UPDATE co_name=bname;
```