# How to use auto-increment Id in another column in same INSERT QUERY in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

How to use auto-increment Id in another column in INSERT QUERY in MYSQL?

I want to add user with code. like if `user_id` after insert is `1` the code will be `US1` similarly if `user_id` after insert is `954` the code will be `US954`

This is what I'm currently doing

```
"INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `user`, `code`) VALUES (NULL, 'Alice', NULL);"
```

and then retrieve last insert id in PHP (Codeigniter)

```
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

and then update code with auto increment id

```
"UPDATE `users` SET `code` = CONCAT('US', '" . $insert_id . "') WHERE `user_id` = " . $insert_id . ";";
```

Is there anyway you can do it in a single INSERT QUERY in MYSQL?

**EDIT:**
This is not same as this [Insert/ update at the same time in a MySql table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677344/insert-update-at-the-same-time-in-a-mysql-table). Because this one asking on concurrent operation of two users simultaneously which is not my question

Comment: No, think about it, you asking if it's possible to get the egg before the chicken has laid it!

Comment: "you asking if it's possible to get the egg before the chicken has laid it!" What makes me wonder was the chicken first or the egg? @SPlatten

Comment: @RaymondNijland lol I get it now.

Comment: @FaizanRupani i believe you are looking for `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`  ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html ) take a look into it... i think you query should be more or less `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (NULL, 'Alice', NULL)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code=CONCAT('US', id);`

Comment: That's different. I have already used it in my project somewhere. It's used for when you already have user_id.

Comment: Yes maybe your better off using a trigger which updates the code column or use MySQL's generated columns (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) for the code column.. something like this `code AS (CONCAT('US', id)`

Comment: problem with triggers; some of the hosting doesn't support it. I'm better of using insert and update query separately

Comment: @RaymondNijland, :) In this case you can get the last insert ID once the record has been inserted, but what is required here is to use the same ID...I would suggest writing a stored procedure which enables you to manage this kind of thing much easier.

Comment: "In this case you can get the last insert ID once the record has been inserted, but what is required here is to use the same ID." i know @SPlatten i did post and removed a answer about `LAST_INSERT_ID()` .. because it didn't know for sure if the topicstarter required that and because it wanted to do it in one query.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.
You can do it using Store Procedure(SP) in MySQL.
You have to call SP one time for each registration instead of twice query(which you did).

It will save lot execution time.

```
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957788/insert-and-update-with-stored-procedure    
    https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php
    https://www.sitepoint.com/stored-procedures-mysql-php/
    http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php
```

Please use above links for more information.

I recommend to use SP for Login/Registration. It will give extra power to your PHP web app.

For your basic example. I've shared similar SP code with you.

```
BEGIN
declare autoIncr int;
//insert code
autoIncr = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
//update code
END
```

Comment: that doesn't give me any solid answer. I don't know what to look for in your answer

Comment: Your questions is, you have to achieve using single query. 
Same, thing you can achieve using single SP call instead of two different call of query.

Comment: If I'm inserting and updating separately in SP, then there is no point of using it. because I can run insert and update query separately in code. And it will take less time as compared to SP.

Comment: SP is take less time. If you will call insert and update query then every time call database server. But in SP, php call database server only time and database server can execute query in single database call instead of twice call of  database.

Comment: To use SP you would have to access to SP permission from hosting provider. Some Hosting Providers doesn't allow it. unless you own your server. And doing insert and update query only makes difference negligible.

Comment: Every hosting provider allowed to use SP. :) which hosting you are using?

Comment: It's working for me, You just make my day.


Thank you dear

Answer (score 0):

Get Newly user_id with MAX(user_id)+1 and then concat it with your string

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`user`, `code`) SELECT 'Alice',CONCAT("US",MAX(user_id)+1) from users
```

Comment: If for example more than 300 people insert simultaneously then you'll have different max user_id for each user. Beside you won't get an actual user_id with MAX(user_id) until you insert the data. otherwise it'll give you last update id

Answer (score -1):

when you created your table and column that time if you given the value of user_id Auto increment. After that when you want to insert the data no need to give value of user_id cause it's will auto incremented

for the create fresh create new table query

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id varchar(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user varchar(255),
    code text,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

that is the inserting query

```
"INSERT INTO `users` (`user`, `code`) VALUES ('Alice', NULL);"
```

Comment: I know. That was sample data. And that's not what I asked